# Facebook Connect Plugin not working with NativeInterface android and iOS

Tags: phonegap-facebook-plugin

I am developing a Phonegap app manually without CLI for both Android and iOS. Earlier I was using openFB Micro-library for Facebook login and everything was running fine in inAppBrowser.

Now there is a change in requirement and I need to use native interface for single sign in. I tried out all plugins, I tried everything present over internet. But nothing is worked out for me. Not even in inAppBrowser.

I tried following:

github.com/jimzim/phonegap-fa...

github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-f...

github.com/Raffaello/phonegap...

github.com/phonegap/phonegap-....

I have provided following in my config.xml

and properly replaced app id and app name.

I have also provided

in config.xml

Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong or provide me any working code.

Also let me know what will be the website URL in Facebook app settings. I have selected www as platform and my code is local i.e, file:///.

Comment: Did you mean to add your `config.xml` into this?